# Flyback CCM right-half-plane-zero and control question

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, control, flyback

The document [Under the Hood of Flyback SMPS Designs](https://www.ti.com/seclit/ml/slup261/slup261.pdf), talks about the RHPZ effect.
I have some questions about that.

1.) Why do we need to design in the low input voltage and maximum current?

2.) I don't very understand what the figure means, can someone explain it to me?

From my understanding, low input voltage and high load current make RHPZ frequency lower.
But I don't understand what this means.

[image]

3.) Why low frequency will make the system hard to compensate?

[image]

Comment: There is a good explanation: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/529081/effect-of-right-half-plane-zero-on-bandwidth-of-control-system

Comment: @Jens,

It is very helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> *Why do we need to design in the low input voltage and maximum current?*

<sub>If the duty cycle increases to compensate for (say) a drop in input voltage, there is an extra-time delay before the output receives its top-up energy. During that added extra-time, the output voltage drops lower than normal and, the expected benefit of increasing duty cycle is temporarily "lost" - this can lead to an instability in the control-loop.</sub>

---

It might help if I plot a few points showing the duty cycle of an ideal flyback converter based around this design on my [rather basic website](http://stades.co.uk/Flyback/flyback%20DCM2.html): -

[image]

The input voltage is nominally 100 volts and the target output voltage is 100 volts into a 300 Ω load (just an example). The duty cycle is 50% (CCM) for 100 volts in. If I vary the input voltage from 20 volts up to 120 volts (a little extreme) you would see the duty cycle vary (blue curve) like this: -

[image]

The important thing that this graph tells you is that the duty cycle has a bigger slope at the lower end of the input supply voltage. This has a significant impact when you consider what happens if the input voltage dropped by 1 volt (for example) and how much the duty cycle might need to compensate to maintain the output voltage at 100 volts.

When the input supply voltage is high (say 100 volts) and it drops to 99 volts, the duty cycle will need to increase from 50.000% to 50.251%. But, that increase in duty cycle is also an increase in the time taken for the secondary circuit (and load) to receive the flyback energy from the primary. The switching frequency in this example is 100 kHz (10 μs period) and so, 0.251% represents an added time delay of 25.1 ns.

Let's run the circuit at (say) 25 volts and then drop it to 24 volts to calculate the the added time delay for the output circuit to receive energy. At 25 volts, the duty cycle is 80.000% and, at 24 volts, the duty cycle is 80.645%. We now have an added time delay of 64.5 ns.

Here's the important bit: -

During the added time delay period, the output voltage drops lower (due to the load current) than it was when the input supply was held constant. And, what will happen is that the control loop's attempt to compensate for the diminishing input supply creates a situation where the output voltage appears to have fallen. This could drive the control circuit into spasms; the output control loop sees an even bigger error on the output and raises duty cycle accordingly. That action produces even more delay and things could spiral out of control rapidly.

In a nutshell, an attempt to counter a drop in the input supply voltage results in the undesired effect of the output voltage dropping (because of load currents) and giving the control loop too many problems.

So, any measures we take to counter this problem MUST work at the lowest input supply voltage and the highest load current; the load current determines how rapidly the output voltage falls during the added time delay.

Comment: Nice intuitive explanation, +1

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate topics here. The small-signal derivation of the RHP zero frequency is beyond the scope of an answer for this site, but given the formula you can assume the following:

A RHP zero causes phase lag and magnitude increase. It can't be cancelled with a RHP pole of course, so compensating a converter with a RHP zero requires closing the loop well before the phase lag and magnitude increase from the RHP zero becomes a problem.

In order to do that, you need to find the worst-case low frequency for the RHP zero. Looking at the graph and the equation it's clear that that happens at low line and high load.

As for voltage mode compensation being harder due to the lower frequency double-pole, you will need a type III compensator, placing two zeros around the LC resonance, a pole at origin and other poles at ESR zero and maybe half the switching frequency. Current mode control doesn't need to cancel the double pole as mentioned so is easier to compensate.

Consider a voltage mode output stage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKSM99.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transfer function is 2 poles with a resonance at $$1/sqrt(2*pi*L*C)$$

Now, if I put an inner current control loop in my converter to control the inductor current, I effectively turn the inductor into a current source as far as the outer voltage loop is concerned:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Yp4x.png)</sup>

Now I only have the single pole response and no resonance to deal with.  In actual practice, the current loop has finite bandwidth so it really just shifts the second pole out to a frequency that's high enough that you don't have to deal with it.  This is all an oversimplifed overview since there are lots of other considerations like peak vs average current mode, subharmonic instability and slope compensation, etc., but you should be able to see the basic idea.

Comment: Hi John,

I understand your explanation, could you explain the last one? "Current mode control doesn't need to cancel the double pole as mentioned so is easier to compensate"
I am not very understadnt it.

Comment: _"I can't be cancelled"_ I assumed you mean It, otherwise please revert my edit.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the derivation of the RHZ; is this with respect to input PWM, or peak current (in a peak current mode control specifically)?

Comment: @winny LOL thanks for the assist.

Comment: @TimWilliams The RHP zero exists any time an increase in duty cycle causes a temporary dip in the output voltage.  Consider a boost converter- Increasing the duty cycle means the inductor current is ramping longer, but the output cap is effectively isolated at that point and the voltage is dropping due to the load during the on time.  (See Andy's answer above)

Comment: @Jitter456 I added some additional information on the second part of your question.

Comment: @JohnD Ok, so for H = Vo / (switch PWM) specifically.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered the meat of the question, so I'll add a related point:

With current mode control, CCM is inherently unstable.  (Indeed, the CCM flyback converter is an analog implementation of the logistic map function.  Theoretically cool, but unfortunately a gremlin in practical use!)  The graph shows RHPZ, in CCM, varying basically with ripple fraction (that is, fRHPZ ~ Fsw * (Ipp/Idc)).

A pure current mode control must either operate in DCM, or tolerate the instability that this chaotic behavior produces (increased input and output ripple current, subharmonic oscillation or noise).

We CCM operation is desirable to reduce core losses, and somewhat reduce input/output capacitor ripple currents.

To stabilize CCM, we can use slope compensation, effectively making a hybrid voltage-current mode control.  (Some regulators provide this, internally fixed, or as a triangular wave current out of their sense pin, thus adjustable with an external resistor; others, you bleed in some of the timing waveform with a few additional components.)  The ratio of current to voltage in the sense signal, is the slope compensation factor, and we need about as much to stabilize the converter to the same ripple fraction (slope factor ~ ripple fraction).

Slope compensation, of course, carries the downside that current limiting depends on pulse width; a slope fraction over 2:1 or so is getting dangerous with respect to overload or short-circuit current limiting (being, again, ballpark 2:1 or more higher than the nominal maximum switching current).

The consequence is, we tend not to use low ripple fractions ("deep" CCM) in peak current mode controls, and thus the RHPZ issue is fairly irrelevant -- it's never very far from Fsw.

(Some of these points are brought up in the appnote; this is partly to emphasize them.  I do note the appnote makes one particular error: instability is NOT due to duty going over 50%, in and of itself: rather it is due to what occurs at that point, i.e., CCM.  Which in turn, only occurs at 50% because of the assumed ratios of Vout/Vin and N2/N1.  *This point is different for other ratios!*  You usually design for nominal operation at up to 50% duty, where this is the case -- but it need not be the case under all conditions, and in particular, isn't the case under startup or fault conditions (Vout less than nominal).)

There are other considerations which make this generally the case; for example, due to the discontinuous primary and secondary currents, we tend to avoid flyback designs at higher power levels, where the input and output capacitors are more costly to handle the ripple, and where higher efficiencies are more desirable.  Thus, peak current mode flyback is common at lower power levels, and higher power levels tend towards forward converters running at deeper CCM, or resonant converters.